# Use Eloquent model method when querying database

Tags: php, database, performance, laravel, eloquent

With an Eloquent Model called `Foo` including a method called `bar`, can I from another function `baz` use `bar` when querying the database? Otherwise I have to call `baz` for every object returned by `bar`.

I would like to do something like this:

```
class Foo extends Model
{
    public function bar
    {
        return Bar::where('foo_id', $this->id)->sum('amount');
    }

    public function baz
    {
        return self::where('col', true)->with('bar')->take(5);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can but the best is to use scopes. This is how you will define scope.

```
public function scopeBaz($query)
{
    return $query->where('col', true)->with('bar')->take(5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Eloquent query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes):

```
class Foo extends Model
{
    public function scopeBar($query)
    {
        return $query->where('foo_id', $this->id)->sum('amount');
    }

    public function baz
    {
        return Bar::where('col', true)->bar()->take(5);
    }
}
```

Also, you can use `bar()` in controller and other classes, not only in model.

Comment: This will return a Bar object, not a Foo object